# Curl-less fields and divergence-less fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I was wondering if anyone could explain some intuition or proof of the two following statements.

$\nabla \times \textbf{F} = 0 \leftrightarrow \textbf{F} = \nabla V$

$\nabla \cdot \textbf{G} = 0 \leftrightarrow \textbf{G} = \nabla \times \textbf{A}$

I understand what they imply when the fundamental theorems of calculus are considered, I am just curious to why one implies the other.

Comment: The implications from right to left are easy to verify (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient ), maybe exercising that through provides some intuition. From left to right is tricky though and has to do with every vector field being the sum of a curl-free field and a divergence-free field ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition ).

Comment: Yeah, right to left is easy, as it's just curl of gradients are zero and divergence of curls are zero. I'm hoping if I can see it better from left to right.

Comment: The intuition is, well, not intuitive. The implication from right to left is that square of exterior derivative is zero. The implication from left to right requires that the domain of definition does not have holes, and the implication is a theorem called Poincaré lemma.

Comment: They're called curl-free and divergence-free (or even better irrotational and solenoidal, respectively), not curl-less and divergence-less

Comment: @Paul being curl-free and divergence-free is a local property, true, but being the gradient or the curl of a function is a global property. Thus in order to establish an implication, global considerations are needed.

Comment: @Paul locally yes, you can write a zero-curl vector field as a gradient of some scalar field. Globally, it may not be the case. A famous example is $F(x,y,z)=(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0)$ defined everywhere except $z$-axis. Similar issues goes for zero-divergence vector fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first identity, the key point is $\boldsymbol\nabla \times\mathbf{F} = 0 \rightarrow\oint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol\ell = 0$ for any closed path. This means that for any two paths from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{x}$,
$$
\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{x}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell_1 - \int^\mathbf{x}_\mathbf{a}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell_2 = \int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{x}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell + \int^\mathbf{a}_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell = \oint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell = 0,
$$
i.e., the integral does not depend on the path taken, only on $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{x}$. Thus, $V(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\mathbf{a}}^\mathbf{x}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol \ell$ is a well-defined scalar function of $\mathbf{x}$, and it can be quickly verified that $\mathbf{F} = \boldsymbol\nabla V$.

I'm currently having trouble coming up with a similar sort of proof for the second case. If you have to, you can just take the curl of the Biot-Savart law,
$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int \left[\mathbf{G(\mathbf{x'})}\times\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|^3}\right]d^3\mathbf{x'} + \boldsymbol\nabla f
$$
and verify that this is the desired $\mathbf{A}$, but that doesn't give much insight as to where the Biot-Savart law comes from (and also requires certain conditions on $\mathbf{A}$ for the integral to converge, I guess).